# Comparar campos entre duas tabelas em PHP x MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom Dia, estou precisando de uma ajuda com umas tabelas em php. 
Tenho duas tabelas das quais preciso comparar dados, as tabelas estão em um banco de dados em MySQL.
O cenario é o seguinte: 
Tenho a tabela1 com as colunas A,B,C,D e a tabela2 com as colunas A,B,C, preciso comparar as colunas A,B,C e se forem iguais me retornar o valor da coluna D, sendo que se D for igual a x o valor total de registros deverá ir para 1/3 de um gráfico e se D for diferente de x o valor total de registros deverá ir para outro 1/3 do gráfico, o outro 1/3 do grafico será populado com uma outra informação que já tenho. 
Alguem poderia me ajudar? Obrigada.

```
Tabela 1
-------------
A | B | C | D
```

...

```
Tabela 2
-------------
A | B | C
```

Answer (score 0):

Poderá fazer da seguinte maneira com a expressão de comparação que age como inner JOIN em SQL:

```
SELECT tabela1.a, tabela1.b, tabela1.c, tabela1.d FROM tabela1 tabela1, 
tabela2 tabela2
WHERE tabela1.a = tabela2.a
AND tabela1.b = tabela2.b
AND tabela1.c = tabela2.c2
AND (ValorX is null or tabela1.d = ValorX)
```